# Launching a VSTO from outside Office

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010, vsto, ms-office, office-interop

I have a VSTO project targeting Excel. I also have a WinForm application written in C#. This is all programmed in C# using .Net Framework 4 and VS 2010.

My problem is that I want to be able to invoke this VSTO application, without first opening Excel. So I will click a button in my WinForm app and it should launch Excel and call the VSTO, which would then read from my database and put some values into the Excel sheet.

Is there an official way of doing this or if not, at least a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is very easy:

1. You call Excel using Automation using something like GetObject method [here more details](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/71044a7d-5424-4c84-94d3-3b29f84b1d2f). As I remember object name will be Excel.Application. This "GetObject" method will either run new instance of Excel (it could be even invisible) or will return you a reference to existing instance.
2. Call your add-on either through Application.COMAddIns or using any other method like WCF - choice of the communication technology is up to you.